# How to share an unmanaged directory between several sub-projects?

Tags: scala, sbt

At the root of my project I have lib directory containing unmanaged jars. 
I would like that this directory is shared as the default unmanaged directory among my sub projects.
I tried this:

```
lazy val project1 = Project(
    id = "project1",
    base = file("project1"),
    settings = buildSettings,
    dependencies = Seq(otherProject))   

project1.settings(unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base.asFile.getParentFile() })
```

Unfortunately when I do "show unmanagedBase" I obtain "./project1/lib" instead of "./lib". 
It seems that my setting to obtain the parent's base is having not effect.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: We have a helper function in our build to do this here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control/blob/master/project/Dependencies.scala#L74:L83

You can see it used throughout our build.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your answer, it works!
I had to add one line to your little DSL to add them to unmanagedJars as well:

```
    def dependsOnSource(dir: String): Seq[Setting[_]] = {
      import Keys._
      Seq(unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <<= (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile, baseDirectory in ThisBuild) { (srcDirs, base) => (base / dir ) +: srcDirs },
baseDirectory in ThisBuild) { (srcDirs, base) => (base / dir ) +: srcDirs },
          unmanagedJars in Compile <++= (baseDirectory in ThisBuild) map { base =>
            ((base / dir) ** "*.jar").classpath
           },

          unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test <<= (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test, baseDirectory in ThisBuild) { (srcDirs, base) => (base / dir ) +: srcDirs })
    }
    implicit def p2source(p: Project): SourceDepHelper = new SourceDepHelper(p)
    final class SourceDepHelper(p: Project) {
      def dependsOnSource(dir: String): Project =
        p.settings(Dependencies.dependsOnSource(dir): _*)
    }
```